# URL.openStream() is very slow when ran on school's unix server

Tags: java, url

I am using `URL.openStream()` to download many html pages for a crawler that I am writing.  The method runs great locally on my mac however on my schools unix server the method is extremely slow.  *But only when downloading the first page.*

Here is the method that downloads the page:

```
public static String download(URL url) throws IOException {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    System.out.println("\t\tCreated 'is' in "+((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/(1000.0*60))+"minutes");
    ...
}
```

And the main method that invokes it:

```
LinkedList<URL> ll = new LinkedList<URL>();
ll.add(new URL("http://sheldonbrown.org/bicycle.html"));
ll.add(new URL("http://www.trentobike.org/nongeo/index.html"));
ll.add(new URL("http://www.trentobike.org/byauthor/index.html"));
ll.add(new URL("http://www.myra-simon.com/bike/travel/index.html"));
for (URL tmp : ll) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(tmp);
    CrawlerTools.download(tmp);
}
```

Output locally *(Note: all are fast)*:

> http://sheldonbrown.org/bicycle.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.00475minutes
>
> http://www.trentobike.org/nongeo/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.005083333333333333minutes
>
> http://www.trentobike.org/byauthor/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.0023833333333333332minutes
>
> http://www.myra-simon.com/bike/travel/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.00405minutes

Output on School Machine Server *(Note: All are fast except the first one.  The first one is slow regardless of what the first site is)*:

> http://sheldonbrown.org/bicycle.html
>                   Created 'is' in 3.2330666666666668minutes
>
> http://www.trentobike.org/nongeo/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.016416666666666666minutes
>
> http://www.trentobike.org/byauthor/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.0022166666666666667minutes
>
> http://www.myra-simon.com/bike/travel/index.html
>                   Created 'is' in 0.009533333333333333minutes

I am not sure if this is a Java issue (*A problem in my Java code) or a server issue.  What are my options?

---

When run on the server this is the output of the time command:

```
real    3m11.385s
user    0m0.277s
sys     0m0.113s
```

I am not sure if this is relevant...  What should I do to try and isolate my problem..?

Comment: What kind of URL is it? Does this happen for any URL or just specific ones? What kind of connection is it?

Comment: Do you still eventually get the complete output, even when it takes 3 minutes? Or does it take 3 minutes just to time out and return no data?

Comment: Are you allowed to run your crawler at school? Anyway, your best bet is to contact school's networkadmin.

Comment: @Perkka, I updated my question.  It happens for all URLs, but only for the first one.  @VoteyDisiple; it always works, it just takes a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question.  It's not a Java issue, it has to do with your school's network or server.

I'd recommend that you report your timings in milliseconds and see if they're *repeatable*.  Run that test in a loop - 1,000 or 10,000 times - and keep track of all the values you get.  Import them into a spreadsheet and calculate some statistics.  Look at the distribution of values.  You don't know if the one data point that you have is an outlier or the mean value.  I'd recommend that you do this for both networks in exactly the same way.

I'd also recommend using Fiddler or some other tool to watch network traffic as you download.  You can get better insight into what's going on and perhaps ferret out the root cause.

But it's not Java.  It's your code, your network.  If this was a bug in the JDK it would have been fixed a long time ago.  Suspect yourself first, last, and always.

UPDATE:

> My network admin assured me that this
>   was a bad java implementation Not a
>   network problem. What do you think?

"Assured" you?  What evidence did s/he produce to support this conclusion?  What data?  What measurements were taken?  Sounds like laziness and ignorance to me.

It certainly doesn't explain why all the other requests behave just fine.  What changed in Java between the first and subsequent calls?  Did the JVM suddenly rewrite itself?

You can accept it if you want, but I'd say shame on your network admin for not being more curious.  It would have been more honorable to be honest and say they didn't know, didn't have time, and weren't interested.

Comment: @duffymo, I have updated my question.  Strangely it ***only*** takes a long time for the first URL.  (I have tried multiple as the first one).

Comment: Probably getting a connection or authentication or something else that's going on behind the scenes.  Perhaps they check credentials, go out to an LDAP server, and cache results for subsequent connections from the same user and server.  Ask your network admin.

Comment: is there a standard (included with linux) equivalent to Fiddler?  How should I isolate the problem?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040642/linux-alternative-to-fiddler2

Comment: @duffymo: Thanks for the help, your comment helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, sixtyfootersdude, but I'd be even happier if you'd accept my answer.  Why would you accept your own answer as correct?  It doesn't seem fair to me.

Comment: done.  Answer accepted.  Putting: `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");` fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice work.  It's good that you posted the answer in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

By Default Java prefers to use IPv6.  My school's firewall
drops all IPv6 traffic (with no warning).  After 3 minutes, 15 seconds Java falls back to IPv4.  Seems strange to me that it takes so long to fall back to IPv4.

[duffymo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953478/url-openstream-is-very-slow-when-ran-on-schools-unix-server/3953493#3953493), essentially: *"Go talk to your network admin"*, helped me to solve the problem however I think that this is a problem caused by a strange Java implementation and a strange network configuration.

My network admin assured me that this was a bad java implementation Not a network problem.  What do you think?